# How do set the amount of list elements equal to the number of characters in a string?

Tags: python, list

When i input a word, for example `data`, I need the amount to elements in a list to be the same as the amount of characters in the example so the list has 4 elements.

edit:

the inputted word would be `data`, the amount of characters in this word would be equal to
the amount of elements, we will use 0's as fillers for now.

```py
word = input(str("Enter word: "))

# I'm not sure what code to use, the word entered would make a list with the amount of elements the same as the 
# amount of characters in the inputted word, using 0's as fillers like:

list = ["0","0","0","0"] # there is 4 characters in the word "data" that was inputted
```

Comment: Clarify the question a bit with piece of input and expected output please.

Comment: What have you already tried? Lists don't have a set size, so what should be the elements? Please [edit] to clarify. BTW welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Can you please clarify what those elements of the list should be? Do you want to store the characters of the word in the list? Are the elements related to the word at all?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `list('Word')` or `[None for _ in 'Word']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help I guess.

```py
word = input("Enter Word: ")

list_ = ["0"] * len(word) 
print(list_)
```

Comment: this is perfect, thank you ( this was probably a dumb question but i'm only yr 10 lol so i'm quite new to python still )

Comment: No worries! this platform is to help others in whatever way we can. And great you learning this now itself. Good Luck!!

Answer (score -2):

I think you want to get a list whose size will be equal to the length of string you entered. If I'm not wrong then following code will help you to get list with any random numbers.

```
import random

s = 'word'
x = random.sample(random.sample([random.randint(1, 11) for i in range(100)], len(s)), len(s))
print(x)
```

This will give output like as:

```
[6, 4, 2, 7]
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Why the random numbers? Why *two* passes of randomness? This seems to needlessly complicate the answer.

Comment: yes, this gave me a result i can work with, i need to string all the values in the list now and it's perfect, also i changed random.randint to 0 to get me where i need

Comment: random numbers are used just because we don't have any output format.